# Overriding a method rules

Tags: blackberry, java-me

The class `LabelField` has a method -

```
public void setPadding(int, int, int, int);
```

If I create a class that extends `LabelField` overriding `setPadding` like so -

```
public class CustomPadding extends LabelField {

    public void setPadding(int, int, int, int){
      super.setpadding(5,5,5,5);
    }
}
```

Every time I create an instance of `CustomPadding` shouldn't my custom `setPadding` method be called ?

Currently it is not, I'm not sure why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would anything automatically be calling the `setPadding` method? It won't be called automatically - something has to actually *call* it, explicitly. Do you have any reason to believe that something in the constructor chain for `LabelField` calls it?

If you're trying to make `customPadding` (which should be named in PascalCase, btw) always set its padding in a particular way, you should call it from the constructor.

Comment: I think setPadding should be called because the paint method of a Field class is called automatically when its overridden. Is this because paint() is abstract?

Comment: @user701254: No, it's because `paint()` is called in order to display a UI at all. It *has* to be called for anything to show up. Methods aren't called magically - something has to call them. It sounds to me like you'd benefit from writing some console apps in Java before moving on to UI code... console apps let you learn more about the language before you get all the complexity of Swing etc.

Answer (score 1):

> **should'nt my custom setPadding method be called ?**

Not if the original `setPadding` wasn't called in the first place.

I.e., the answer is, yes, `customPadding.setPadding` should be called whenever `LabelField.setPadding` would have been called if it was a `LabelField`. (But if `LabelField.setPadding` *wouldn't have been called*, neither should `customPadding.setPadding`.)

You should provide a bit more code. (I for instance assume you actually have names for your parameters in `customPadding`.)

Comment: ok, LabelField should be calling setpadding in its constructor for it to be called ?

Comment: *Someone* should call `setPadding` sometime, for the method to execute. That is, `LabelField` calling `setPadding` in it's constructor is a *sufficient* but not *necessary* condition.